# ExtJS Amazon SDK

Tags: javascript, extjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a web application built solely in ExtJS (Sencha Architect). I have one JSON blob that I am using for all my data, and to now I have been using my browsers local storage.

Is it possible to use the AWS Javascript SDK to put/get a JSON blob from an ExtJS web app to storage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add "resources" to your application in Sencha Architect, which can either be local or remote.

Comment: and if I don't use Sencha Architect, how can it be done?

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at Sencha, but I think you can still add "resources" via Sencha Cmd (assuming you're using that). Honestly you're better off asking this question in the Sencha forums.